# Exclude specific product categories on Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to exclude some categories from being displayed on the WooCommerce product page.

*Example*: if in a single product page I have "Categories: Cat1, Cat"2",  I want that only Cat1 will be displayed.

I tried editing the *meta.php* in the single-product template.
I created a new function:

```
$categories = $product->get_category_ids();
$categoriesToRemove = array(53,76,77,78); // my ids to exclude
foreach ( $categoriesToRemove as $categoryKey => $category) {
    if (($key = array_search($category, $categories)) !== false) {
        unset($categories[$key]);
    }
}
$categoriesNeeded = $categories;
```

Then I have the echo from WooCommerce:

```
echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count($categories), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );
```

But it still shows the same categories. The strange thing is that when I do a `var_dump($categories)` it shows the correct thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try this custom function hooked in `get_the_terms` filter hook, that will exclude specific product categories to be displayed on single product pages:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'custom_product_cat_terms', 20, 3 );
function custom_product_cat_terms( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ){
    // HERE below define your excluded product categories Term IDs in this array
    $category_ids = array( 53,76,77,78 );

    if( ! is_product() ) // Only single product pages
        return $terms;

    if( $taxonomy != 'product_cat' ) // Only product categories custom taxonomy
        return $terms;

    foreach( $terms as $key => $term ){
        if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ){
            unset($terms[$key]); // If term is found we remove it
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: This is cool, +1 - I would be interested to hear why you opted for `get_the_terms` as opposed to `get_terms`? Is it just personal preference, or is there an advantage there?

Comment: @Frits Thanks :) … Because it's the root function involved here to get the terms before being formatted and displayed (on single product pages).

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you so much, you're a life saver :)

Comment: Actually it was my first time doing this, so thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

add the below code to `single-product.php`

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'organicweb_exclude_category', 10, 3 );
function organicweb_exclude_category( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
  $new_terms = array();
  // if a product category and on a page
  if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_page() ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
// Enter the name of the category you want to exclude in place of 'uncategorised'
      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'uncategorised' ) ) ) {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
      }
    }
    $terms = $new_terms;
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a filter on the `get_terms` hook, and then excluding the above-mentioned category ID's from the terms list if `get_terms()` was run on a single product page **and** if the terms being fetched are `product_cat`'s.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'danski_single_product_exclude_category', 10, 3 );
function danski_single_product_exclude_category( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_categories = array();
    // if a product category and a single product
    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_product() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term->term_id, array( 53,76,77,78 ) ) ) { //add the category id's that you want to exclude here
                $new_categories[] = $term;
            }
        }
        $terms = $new_categories;
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

You can add this code to your `functions.php`.

Comment: Nope... still there! And I actually tried the solution before my code adventure :)

Comment: @danski - I've edited the answer. Have a go with the new code and let me know if it works for you? I completely misread your question, and previously gave you code that would remove those product categories from the shop archive page... _*facepalm_

Comment: Still not working :( There's a working solution up and I think you and I can learn both....

Comment: Also, thank you for your time! You also have a virtual beer from me :)